# Is it possible to change salesforce picklist field from one global picklist into another

Tags: picklist

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible for a Salesforce field to switch from one global picklist into another? Trying to click around but didn't find the option

Answer (score 4):

Funny you should ask this as we were trying this just today...

The answer is NO; [from the Help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=picklist_limitations.htm&type=5)

> You can’t undo a custom picklist field’s association with a global value set. If you need a picklist field to use a different global value set, or different individual values, delete the custom picklist field and create a new one in its place.

**Side note:** You can rename the global value set and the custom field(s) that use it will automatically change to the new reference - but deploying that can't be done with the metadata API